# Skipping digits of a number and adding the non-skipped ones in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to get every other digit from a user-inputted number. And then find their sum. For example, 123456. I want to get 5,3, and 1. Then find their sum. This is my function for that:

```c
int getSum(long userInput) // user input being passed as an argument.
{
   long userInput1 = userInput;
   long sumOfNum = 0 ;

 while(userInput1 != 0)
    {
      userInput1 = userInput1 / 10;
      sumOfNum += userInput1 % 10;
    }

  printf("%ld\n",sumOfNum);
}
```

This doesn't work for all of the numbers, for example; with 12345, I am expecting 6. But the output is 10.

Where did I go wrong?

[Edit- How I did it? (based on the answer from [Fe2O3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73355824/17247979))
I need another division. So:

```c
 while(userInput1 != 0)
    {
      userInput1 = userInput1 / 10;
      sumOfNum += (userInput1 % 10);
      userInput1 = userInput1 / 10; // this one
    }
   printf("%ld\n",sumOfNum);
   return sumOfNum;
}
```

Comment: `userInput1 = userInput1 % 10;`  --> The upper digits are lost.

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko thank you for replying, I fixed but it still doesn't work for all the numbers. If I have something like 101010, it gives 3 as expected. But not for other odd numbers. What might be a better approach?

Comment: Please don't answer the question inside the question. However, you may post an answer to your own question. See this official help page for further information: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get every other digit...

```
int getSum( long val ) {
    int sum = 0;
    for( val /= 10; val; val /= 100 )
        sum += val % 10;

    printf( "%d\n", sum );

    return sum; // missed this in previous version
}
```

EDIT:

After it was pointed out that 'sum' went out of scope after the `for()` terminated, the code has been adapted to have fewer division operations.